# Prevent certain AWS AMI from accidental deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, delete-file, amazon-ami

When cleaning up the old/unused resources, at times we may get into trouble deleting the used/current AMIs. 
Have to prevent the accidental delete/deregister of the AMIs.

I was thinking to add a tag to the AMI which should never be deleted if that tags exist.

In a similar fashion to instance termination protection, 
I would like the ability to have CERTAIN AMI's have a double failsafe mechanism to avoid accidental deletion.

Please suggest a way for the same.

Comment: I understand that IAM Policy can restrice the deletion of AMIs. But this will do for all AMI.. 
I have to apply failsafe mechanism to only selected certain AMIs.

Comment: It's surprising that there's not an easy way to achieve this in AWS. In Azure you can just lock resources which requires unlocking in order to make changes. Even just making a backup of the AMI to S3 is not trivial. Weak.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** `DeregisterImage()` now *does* have Condition Keys, so this answer is out-of-date.

---

Based on [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon EC2 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html), it appears that `DeregisterImage()` does not have any Condition Keys.

Therefore, it looks like it would not be possible to restrict this command only to certain AMIs or tags.

Some options:

- Restrict this permission only to certain trusted users, *or*
- Put the AMI in a separate AWS account where users can access it (via sharing), but have no permission to delete it

Comment: Thanks for the response @John. Is there way that I can add to IAM Policy specifying some conditions to it for certain AMIs.

Comment: As per above, the documentation indicates that this is not possible. (But if you find a way, let us know!)

Comment: As of 2021-01-20, it appears that `DeregisterImage` _does_ have Condition Keys associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

One more option.
You can enable Recycle Bin with retention rule for AMI which is used to restore the AMI or snapshots from the AWS Recycle Bin console, if you accidentally deleted the AMI's or Snapshots .

Navigate to AWS Recycle Bin then choose "Create a new retention rule".

[image: RecycleBin - Create a Retention Rule]

At the Retention Settings, You can select specific AMI's or All the AMI's and choose retention period you want.

[image: Retention settings]

Then create a Retention rule for AMI.

[image: Retention Rule]

After wards, You can see the accidentally deleted AMI resource from Recycle Bin - Resources

Prior to use, You can test this with any Test AMI.